# Access Jira from eclipse java for ETL process

Tags: java

We have a Project tracking tool  named Jira . I want to use Core java skills to extract number of  defects from JIRA and transform into excel. Let me now how to do the handshaking between JIRA and eclipse.

Comment: Search for Jira APIs > https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/
Atlassian exposes REST endpoints that you can access through java.

Comment: Could you please add more to it

Answer (score 0):

For getting the dependency, its called jira rest java client ([JRJC](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JRJC/overview))

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m15</version>
</dependency>
```

and then authenticate (eg. [basic authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/about-the-jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication)),

```
final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "admin", "admin");
try {
    final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("TST-7").claim();
    println(issue);
}
finally {
    // cleanup the restClient
    restClient.close();
}
```

or use [OAuth](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/about-the-jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication?_ga=2.90955998.536748480.1512477306-672434411.1512477306).

Once authenticated, use the list of apis provided - [Jira Cloud REST API Reference.](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2)